# How to exit father function based on child function return value?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#make your own choice,decide which function should be run
set -e
keyin(){
    read -e -p "$1 input y，otherwise input n" local yorn
    if [[ "y" == "$yorn" || "Y" == "$yorn" ]]; then
        return 0
    fi
}
fun1(){
    keyin 'update software no.1'
    echo 'how to exit this function?'
}
fun2(){
keyin 'update software no.2'
echo "fun2 is still running"
}
fun1
fun2
```

When I run this script, and I input `y`,I want to exit `fun1` and continue to run `fun2`.
How to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about handling the return value of the function?

```
keyin() {
    # read -e -p "$1 input y，otherwise input n" local yorn
    yorn=n
    if [[ "y" == "$yorn" || "Y" == "$yorn" ]]; then
        return 0
    fi
    return 1 # return nonzero in case of error
}

fun1() {
    # handle the return value - in case of non-zero execute custom action
    if ! keyin 'update software no.1'; then
        return
    fi
    echo 'how to exit this function?'
}

fun2() {
    echo "fun2 is still running"
}

fun1
fun2
```

Simple `if function; then` let's you execute an action depending if the return value of a function was zero or non-zero.

The statement `read .... local yorn` reads a value in a variable named `local`. I think you meant just `read .... yorn` without the `local` word.

Comment: `return 1` will exit whole script because of `set -e`

Comment: The statement `read .... local yorn` reads a variable named `yorn` ,`local` means local variable.

Comment: @kittygirl No, it will not. `set -e` exit the script in case of "non handled" return values. So `false` will exit the script. But `if false; then true; else true; fi` will not, because the statement `if` returns true value. The `if ... ; then ... fi;` is parsed as one statement for `set -e`. The return value of an `if` is the last command executed, so `if true; then false; fi` will exit the script nonetheless.

Comment: @kittygirl No, it does not. The string `local` in `read .. local` is interpreted as a variable name. You want `local yorn; read ... yorn`.